# Efficiency in Populating complex object properties (lists) with LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

Alright, this one will have quite a bit of code in it, and may be somewhat long. That said, I'm really having trouble finding the best way to do this, and any help would be immensely appreciated. I am here to learn, specifically the most efficient way to write these types of queries.

**NOTE: The system I'm working with right now is an ASP.NET MVC site written in VB.NET, using Entity Framework 6.**

With all that out of the way, I believe my best bet here is to just show an example, and see what options are available. My issue comes in to play when I need to populate an object's properties utilizing a LINQ to Entities query hitting the database, but some of those properties are lists themselves of both simple integers, as well as more complex objects. For example, take this query:

Note that in the code example below I removed a complex WHERE clause and some other irrelevant to the question properties I populate to make it smaller and easier to read.

```
//NOTE: If any context is needed to better understand this, I can provide it. I do provide a bit in the comments. Actual code uses ' for comments (VB). 

/*Context: db is an instance of the EF context. Code is representing threads
and replies in an "activity feed". Threads can have private recipients and
uploads, both of which are grabbed from the database. These are the two
properties I'm populating which this question addresses further down.*/

//Get all my activity feed threads
  model.ActivityFeedThreads = (From thds In db.tblThreads
                               From thps In db.tblThreadParticipants.Where(Function(w) w.thpThread_thdID = thds.thdID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                               Join prns In db.tblPersons On thds.thdOwner_prnID Equals prns.prnID
                               Join emps In db.tblEmployees On prns.prnID Equals emps.empPerson_prnID
                               Where (thps Is Nothing And thds.thdPrivacy_lvlID = ActivityThread.ActivityThreadPrivacy.PublicThread) _
                               Select New ActivityThread With {.thdID = thds.thdID,
                                                               .Content = thds.thdContent,
                                                               .ThreadOwner_prnID = thds.thdOwner_prnID,
                                                               .PrivacyOption_lvlID = thds.thdPrivacy_lvlID,
                                                               .ThreadDate = thds.thdDateCreated}).Distinct().Take(20).OrderByDescending(Function(o) o.ThreadDate).ToList()
```

Now, one property which I need to populate that is not included in that query is "AttachedFiles", which is a list of type "AppFile", a custom class in our system. In addition, there is a second property called "PrivateRecipients", which is a list of simple Int32s. I have tried to work those in to the above query without success, so I have to loop through the resulting list and populate them, resulting in numerous hits to the database. Below is my current code:

```
  //I need to get the private recipients for this post.. Is there a way to work this in to the above query? What's the most efficient solution here?
  For Each threadToEdit In model.ActivityFeedThreads
    threadToEdit.PrivateRecipients = db.tblThreadParticipants.Where(Function(w) w.thpThread_thdID = threadToEdit.thdID).Select(Function(s) s.thpPerson_prnID).ToList()
  Next

  //Again, loop through, grab all attached files. Similar situation as above.. Can I work it in to the query?
  For Each threadToEdit In model.ActivityFeedThreads
    threadToEdit.AttachedFiles = (From flks In db.tblFileLinks
                                  Join fils In db.tblFiles On flks.flkFile_filID Equals fils.filID
                                  Where flks.flkTarget_ID = threadToEdit.thdID And flks.flkLinkType_lvlID = AppFile.FileLinkType.Thread_Upload
                                  Select New AppFile With {.filID = fils.filID,
                                                           .Location = fils.filLocation,
                                                           .FileURL = fils.filLocation,
                                                           .Name = fils.filName,
                                                           .FileName = fils.filName,
                                                           .MIMEType = fils.filMIMEType}).ToList()
  Next
```

As you can see, in both situations, I'm having to loop through and hit the database a bunch of times, and I have to imagine as the data grows this will become a bit of a bottleneck.. Is there a better way to go about this with LINQ to Entities? Should I change my approach altogether?

Thank you in advance for your time/help, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take out all of your .ToList() calls. That will keep everything as an IQueryable until it actually needs to go to the database. This may not solve your issue completely, but it's a step in the right direction. Try it and report back if there's any improvement on the number of round trips to the db.

Comment: You can declare your "AttachedFiles" as IEnumerable<AppFile>, not List<AppFile>. Then you can include it in main query and (unless query is really complicated) it will be fetched in one query.

Comment: I'll give these a shot and report back in just a bit - thanks for the input, and anyone else with more feel free to add on, I'll take all the info I can get :)

Comment: Once you get it working without the ToList() calls (thus allowing the EF framework to run the most efficient queries it can, later than before), can you add the T-SQL it generates for one of the suspected inefficient queries?  You can get the T-SQL in the debugging watch window or in your logging code by calling .ToString() on the IQueryable.

Comment: Been having some issues removing .ToList in certain areas, mostly due to properties inside those objects which are also Lists. I'm working on it, but due to my current timelines (always down to the wire in this project... never give us time for stuff like this) it might be tomorrow or tonight before I've responded. Also, @PatrickSzalapski - Thanks for the insight, I didn't know how to view the generated T-SQL, so I'm excited to play with that this evening! Thanks all, I'll be sure to respond with my results!